# Edit or update ArcGIS Online Web Map data using the REST API

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api

[Web Map data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Web_map_data/02r30000003p000000/) is described on the ArcGIS REST API site under the *Common data types section*.  I am curious whether I can request the current JSON configuration as shown in the [examples](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Single_basemap_layer/02r30000004t000000/) (using */data* in the url), modify it, and POST it back?  As an example, I could request the web map data, add or modify the [bookmarks](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Bookmarks/02r300000044000000/) list (by editing the JSON web map data, see example [here](http://www.arcgis.com/sharing/content/items/70d051ddd6b5490394623a2715afc584/data?f=pjson)), and submit the update to modify the web map item in ArcGIS Online.  Does a REST operation or alternative exist for this?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/arcpy/AutomaticUpdatesIntoFeatureService/blob/master/UpdatePointFromExternalAPI.py  - does this do what you want?

Comment: Thanks @KHibma, I would like to update properties of the web map (bookmarks) and am not interested in updating map or feature services.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Update Item](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Update_Item/02r30000009s000000/) operation is how to do this.  See helpful post on [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/message/448220#448220).

I was not sure how to implement Update Item or what parameter to use to POST the data I was requesting and modifying.  I think I was confused between the Items [common parameters](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Common_parameters/02r30000009v000000/) (such as tags, title, type, etc.) and the actual content (data) of the item (bookmarks, extent, etc.) which is what I wanted to update (by appending bookmark JSON as @crmackey suggested).  The solution for me was after requesting and modifying the [Item Data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Item_Data/02r300000075000000/), I made a POST request with the modified JSON as the ***text*** parameter of the Update Item operation.

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely possible if the service is a FeatureService.  I would do this using Python and either the built-in urllib modules or with requests (my preferred choice).

This [example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Update_Features/02r3000000zt000000/) shows how to update features. You can also add features and delete features.

Edit:

You can probably just append a bookmark to the list of bookmarks.  You can see this when you view the JSON:

```
 {
      "extent": {
        "spatialReference": {"wkid": 102100},
        "xmax": -2050429.2553922953,
        "xmin": -9946068.529135762,
        "ymax": 1287382.3514782274,
        "ymin": -4299247.17182725
      },
      "name": "(Initial view of Brazil)"
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @crmackey.  In this case, the example I gave re: bookmarks is what I would like to achieve.  I am not interested in the the map or feature services but in updating properties of the web map such as the bookmarks.

Comment: @amarinel Sorry, I misunderstood your question.  You can probably just append a bookmark to the list of bookmarks through a python POST request.  I edited my question to show an example from the link you provided.  I am not 100% sure if this will work though.

Comment: Thanks again.  I did figure it out.  A POST request is exactly what I needed...I just wasn't sure which operation to use.  I needed to use [Update Item](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/index.html#/Update_Item/02r30000009s000000/)...makes perfect sense...but I was getting confused between item details and the actual item data/content.